# Бесконечный редерикт при получении Standalone-токена VK.API на PHP

Tags: php

Чтобы использовать `wall.post` `VK.API` необходим токен standalone приложения. Его можно получить путем выполнения запроса на сервер `API`, делая вид, маскируясь под этот самый `Standalone`. Метод был рабочий и год назад, и неделю назад. Спустя неделю, появилась необходимость повторить операцию. 
Вот тот самый запрос, ничего необычного:

```
$ch =  curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6049967&display=page&revoke=1&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=wall,offline&response_type=token&v=5.64&state=12341");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

После открытия страницы с кодом сверху по соответствующему адресу начинается веселье: бесконечный редерикт на этот самый скрипт. 
[image: По запросу раз в секунду]

[image: Собственно то, что мне пытается вывести VэКэ]

ВКонтакте само собой авторизован. Никаких приблуд в `.htaccess` не навешано. Полагаю, двухфакторка никак не должна повлиять на результаты получения токена? Что думаете по вопросу? Может, кто-нибудь попробует повторить мои манипуляции, буду признателен. 
Попробовал разные типы вывода получения доступа. И попробовал разные приложения. Даже новое зарегал. Обращаться, думаю, в СПП бесполезно, просто ткнут в документацию, которую я уже наизусть выучил. А через `JS` можно как-нибудь проделать подобное, если совсем не получился разобраться?

Comment: Куки не пробовали сохранять/отдавать в curl?

Comment: СП там очень даже ничего, в доки не ткнут

Comment: может ид приложения скажете? а то каждый кто захочет попробовать у себя запустить код должен будет генерировать приложение vk.

Comment: @visman попробую сейчас. Хотя не до конца представляю, какие кукисы ему нужны.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan добавил client_id

Comment: @DuBaH Хорошо вечером посмотрю и дам вам знать что получиться.

Comment: Перезагрузка страницы происходит при выводе результата: и `echo`, и `var_dump`. Отписал поддержке, попробую общий язык найти с ними.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения `access_token` как для `standalone` с помощью `php` нужно сделать вот что:

`$url="https://oauth.vk.com/authorizeclient_id=6049967&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=wall&response_type=token&v=5.64&state=12341";
echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Нажми на меня</a>';`

В таком случае после перехода по ссылке и подтверждения в адресной строке будет необходимый токен. Никаких велосипедов с `curl-ами` изобретать не надо.